# How to easily work with python strings containing both single and double quotes?

Tags: python, string, escaping

How to easily work with python strings containing both single and double quotes?

I do have some complex bash lines that do contain: single quotes, double quotes and escapes too and I do want to migrate them to python and I am looking for an easy way to do this, that would minimize the changes needed to these lines, ideally to keep them bash-compatible.

Example:

```
  #/bin/bash
  psql -h hostname db -c "\copy (select sr, id, rc AS jql from sr UNION select 'quickfilter', \"ID\", \"QUERY\" from \"AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER\") TO xxx.csv"
```

As you can see it contains `"`, `'`, escapes too... making quite ugly to re-escpaes them when moving them to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triple quotes with r-prefix to prevent backslashes from having special meaning:

```
r'''\copy (select sr, id, rc AS jql from sr UNION select 'quickfilter', "ID", "QUERY" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER") TO xxx.csv'''
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfe let's that that my example was minimal, I already have many simple escapes and double ones...

Comment: So ...?  What are you trying to imply?

Comment: just scroll my sample line and you'll see. I guess there is no better approach on this :(

Comment: I did read your example (again now) but I still don't understand what you mean.  I can guess, but in various ways, so it really would help if you could be a bit less vague :-}

Comment: Especially when quoting and escaping are involved precise use of language is required in order not to be misunderstood, that's why I'm a bit stubborn about guessing here.  Nothing personal, its just my experience that things are easily being misunderstood in these contexts.